# How do I include a TinyMCE editor in the frontend?

Tags: tinymce, front-end

I am trying to add a TinyMCE editor in my frontend from where users can post but have had no luck so far. Here is the code:

**PHP:**

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');

function my_enqueue_scripts() {      
        wp_enqueue_script( 'tiny_mce' );
        if (function_exists('wp_tiny_mce')) wp_tiny_mce();
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple", 
        /*plugins : "autolink, lists, spellchecker, style, layer, table, advhr, advimage, advlink, emotions, iespell, inlinepopups, insertdatetime, preview, media, searchreplace, print, contextmenu, paste, directionality, fullscreen, noneditable, visualchars, nonbreaking, xhtmlxtras, template",*/
        editor_selector :"editor"
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<textarea rows="8" cols="40" name="description" id="editor" class="required"><?php echo $description;?></textarea>
```

**Problem:** Texteditor not adding to textarea. Although the TinyMCE js file is loading.

Comment: Perhaps you'll find some inspiration by looking at the code of the [Frontend Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, Thanks to wp 3.3 now we have [`wp_editor()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/) function to do that :)

Comment: Yes, except it outputs the editor directly, as opposed to allowing you to use it in a shortcode...

Comment: You can use this in a shortcode by using the php ob_content functions. These functions allow you to capture the output in a variable. Like so: 
        ob_start();
        include( static::getTemplatePath() . '/' . $templatePath . '.php');
        $template = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $template;

Answer (score 2):

`editor_selector` is for targeting classes, not ids.

Also, when using `editor_selector`, it is required to set `mode: "specific_textareas"` in order for it to work.

See http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:editor_selector

So your JavaScript and HTML should look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        theme : "simple", 
        /*plugins : "autolink, lists, spellchecker, style, layer, table, advhr, advimage, advlink, emotions, iespell, inlinepopups, insertdatetime, preview, media, searchreplace, print, contextmenu, paste, directionality, fullscreen, noneditable, visualchars, nonbreaking, xhtmlxtras, template",*/
        editor_selector :"tinymce-enabled"
    });
});
```

```
<textarea rows="8" cols="40" name="description" id="editor" class="tinymce-enabled required"><?php echo $description;?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Altough @maryisdead answer might be right, i'll give you another tip, first make sure there's only one element in your page with the id="editor" then setup tinymce like so:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "editor"
});
```

Also use jQuery instead of $ in your javascript code to make sure you are calling jQuery methods and selectors.

Answer (score 0):

editor_selector is for classes and not for ids.

You should use editor_selector's value as the class name of the textarea.